# I am working with exponential equations and models.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

[The original problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cX3Dn.png)
[What I have tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWN9l.jpg)
From the information given in the problem we have the points $(5,360)$ and $(20,1000)$

I found a solution online that used the solution to find k shown on the right of the whiteboard. I know that this is the correct answer because that is the answer in the book and I worked it out another way and got the same answer.

$\frac{360}{1000}=\frac{A_0e^{k5}}{A_0e^{k20}}$
$\frac{9}{25}=e^{-15k}$

$\ln\left(\frac{9}{25}\right)=-15k$

$k=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{9}{25}\right)}{-15}$

I would just like to understand why we are allowed to do that.

While trying to understand I tried what is written on the right in red, but that is not the solution that I got on the right. Can someone please help me understand why that isn't correct

$360=A_0e^{5k}$

$0=A_0e^{5k}-360$

$1000=A_0e^{20k}$

$0=A_0e^{20k}-1000$

$A_0e^{5k}-360=A_0e^{20k}-1000$

$e^{15k}=640$

$\ln(640)=15k$

$k=\frac{\ln(640)}{15}$

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. If you want help here, take the time to write your mathematics for us (reading images is hard). Clearly explain what you are confident of and what you doubt. Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: In your calculation you made an error and it should be,
$$A_0e^{5k}-360=A_0e^{20k}-1000$$ 
$$A_0e^{20k}-A_0e^{5k}= 640\quad \text{or}\quad A_0(e^{20k}-e^{5k}) = 640$$As you can see, in this way we are still left with $A_0$ and $k$. But in the calculation you presented earlier we just insert each points (i.e $(x_0,y_0)$ or in your case $(5,360)$, $(20,1000)$) in the function $y = A_0 e^{kx}$. Then we get two equation and after dividing, $A_0$ will be eliminated and the $k$ can be calculated. Now plug in the value of $k$ in one of the equations and obtain $A_0$.

Comment: Okay I see my error now thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are making fundamental mistakes.

*Firstly*, you have treated $A_0$ as if it is $1$

If you proceeded to first find $k$, you would get $k= 0.068110$,
and to find $A_0$, you'd solve$A_0*e^{(5*0.068110)}=360 \Longrightarrow A_0 =256$

and you'd find that $A_0e^{5k} = 360, A_0e^{20k} = 1000$

*secondly*, you can't **subtract** as $e^{15k} = 1000-360$,
you should revise the laws of exponents

Comment: Yeah I'm still learning the fundamentals that's why I'm on here asking a question, but I appreciate you taking the time to give me some feedback

Comment: So hope you now understand.

Comment: I understand the second half now, but with the first half of my problem why are we able to set $\frac{360}{1000}=\frac{A_0e^{5k}}{A_0e^{20k}}$

Comment: We have just divided one equation by another. There's nothing wrong with it, as neither of them is zero.

Comment: Is there some sort of law or property that allows us to do that?

Comment: You can always divide one equation by another as long as division by zero doesn't occur. In exponential growth or decay, such a division helps us to figure out "k"